# How can I catch exception from different Class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        void func1() throw(){
            cout << "func1 throw 1\n";
            throw 1;
        }
};

class B{
    public:
        A a;
        void func2(){
            try{
                a.func1();
            }
            catch(int e){ //terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
                cout << "func2 catch " <<e;
            }
        }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    b.func2();
    return 0;
}
```

This is simplified version of my problem...
There is a function from class A, A::func1().
And it throw 1;

And then there is class B, which calls A::func1() from func2().
and I made try-catch clause to catch the thrown 1 from A::func1(), and from now I got a problem...

When I called B::func2() from main() then I got a runtime error
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'".

This problem is occured in "g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609"
and it works properly in "Visual Studio 2017" in "Window 10"!!

So, I think this problem is concerned with compiler or OS.
Can u explain me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: As an advice use the proverb: "throw by value, catch by reference".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Answers go below, matey

Comment: Next time please continue simplifying the problem until you have the most minimal version you can make. All of the class stuff is irrelevant here. You'd eventually have tried removing `throw()` (as it would be the last thing left) and found it was the problem, leading you to look up what it actually means as you should have done when you wrote it....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with classes, be they the same or otherwise.

```
void func1() throw(){
  cout << "func1 throw 1\n";
  throw 1;
}
```

`func1` has `throw()` on it, which means "this function won't throw exceptions".

Then it throws an exception.

This causes a call to `std::terminate`, because it is wrong.

You see different behaviour on Windows because, in certain modes when using Visual Studio, [the result is undefined without `std::terminate` being called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-specifications-throw-cpp?view=vs-2017), which is also wrong.

**Remove the `throw()`.**

Comment: `If Visual Studio accepts this, then Visual Studio is also wrong.` Why?

Comment: @user2079303 The standard tells us what should happen, and if that does not happen, the compiler is wrong.

Comment: That I agree with. I guess it is unclear what you meant by "accepts this".

Comment: Yup, it's mentioned on their msdn that they handle `throw` a bit differently. So you should always use `noexcept` if you want conformant (to the latest standard) behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-specifications-throw-cpp?view=vs-2017
Or use /std:c++17 switch where this is fixed.

Comment: @DanM. Good find!

Comment: @DanM.: _"The function can throw an exception of type `type`. The compiler accepts the syntax, but interprets it as `noexcept(false)`."_ lol.. cowboys.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit doesn't matter since it's removed (as `throw()` soon will be) ;P

Comment: Aha! I now understand what were those Warning... Those mean that those functions can't throw but they throw...

Answer (score 5):

`throw()` is a deprecated synonym for `noexcept`, i.e. your function will never throw anything.
Letting an unhandled exception out of a `noexcept` function results in an immediate call to `std::terminate`.

Comment: `throw()` is not a direct synonym for `noexcept`, the behaviour is actually subtly different. An exception propagating from a `noexcept` function calls `std::terminate` directly, but an exception propagating from a `throw()` function should call `std::unexpected` -- which is a configurable handler that, by default, delegates to `std::terminate`.

Comment: @Bitwize [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) states clearly that it is "[the] same as `noexcept(true)`".

Comment: They are synonyms as of C++17.

Comment: @Quentin Huh, I wasn't aware that C++17 changed this to be identical behaviour! Thanks for the correction, I guess my information was outdated.

Comment: @Bitwize my pleasure! Exceptions are a but of a bumpy road for the committee and it's hard to keep track of everything, I had to check :)

Comment: And `throw()` is removed since C++20

Comment: @DanM. hence "deprecated", but we're not there quite yet.